# Difference between type and class in fortran 2003

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I have been told for my PhD that I have to learn fortran 2003 language.  I have never used and OOP program before nor fortran.  I am trying to understand what the difference between type and class is. I know that classes are declared with the 'TYPE' keyword but I have also seen examples of the keyword 'CLASS' being used used so I am getting confused.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 16):

The keyword `type` is used to declare *derived types* -- best not to get into the habit of thinking, perhaps imported from foreign languages, that `type` is used for declaring something called `classes`.

The keyword `class` is used, in restricted circumstances, to mean `of the type specified or any of its extended types`.  *extended type* is Fortran-speak for a type which extends another type, essentially one which *specialises* or *inherits from* another type.  The restricted circumstances within which `class` is used are in procedure dummy-argument lists and in declarations of entities with the attribute `allocatable` or the attribute `pointer`.  A `class` entity gets a dynamic `type` at run-time, and its dynamic type may vary from run to run, or across a single execution of the program.

If you don't understand the explanation in the previous paragraphs it's possibly because I've explained things poorly, but it's also possibly because you don't yet have enough of a grounding in the basics of Fortran.  To acquire the grounding find yourself an up-to-date online tutorial, an online reference guide, and start programming.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response.  Some of it makes sense  I think you are right that I haven't really fully grasped the basics yet. Unfortunately need to produce some results soon, so need to find a crash course.

Comment: Try to understand *dynamic dispatch*, the key thing in OOP. The whole class thing and the type-bound procedures are about that.

Comment: @Tori A crash course is here: https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n1a3.htm and https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n2a2.htm

Comment: Just for completeness, there is one more article (on parameterized derived types), which would be too advanced for Tori (I think) but useful to some: https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v5n2a4.htm