# How to have an allocatable array of variable rank (number of dimensions)?

Tags: fortran, allocatable-array

I have two programs : 2D and 3D versions.
For example, this is a simplified 2D version :

```
program main

    integer, parameter :: nDim = 2
    integer :: size
    real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: myArray

    size=4 ! Normally read from a file
    allocate(myArray(1:size,1:size,1:nDim))
    call initArray(myArray)

contains
    
    subroutine initArray(myArray)
    
        real, dimension(1:size,1:size,1:nDim) :: myArray
    
        myArray(1:size,1:size,1:nDim) = 5.d0
     
        return  
    end subroutine initArray
    
end program main
```

And the 3D version,

```
program main

    integer, parameter :: nDim = 3
    integer :: size
    real, dimension(:,:,:,:), allocatable :: myArray

    size=4 ! Normally read from a file
    allocate(myArray(1:size,1:size,1:size,1:nDim))
    call initArray(myArray)

contains
    
    subroutine initArray(myArray)
    
        real, dimension(1:size,1:size,1:size,1:nDim) :: myArray
    
        myArray(1:size,1:size,1:size,1:nDim) = 5.d0
     
        return  
    end subroutine initArray
    
end program main
```

These programs are very similar and I would like to have only one program where the parameter `nDim` determine everything.

But I have problem with the following statements and instructions :

1. For `dimension`, I have not the same number of dimensions (3 or 4)
2. For `allocate`, the number of arguments is variable (3 or 4)
3. For initialisating `myArray`, the number of dimension is variable (3 or 4)

Is there a solution purely in fortran or should I use the C preprocessor ?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: The situation hasn't really changed since this previous Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328846/dynamic-dimensions-of-arrays/ - similar questions continue to pop up with some regularity.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark. So cpp is the solution ? Or is there anohter one ?

Comment: If you follow the chain of answers I pointed you at and read them you'll see there are a number of Fortran approaches to solving your problem.  I don't know what you mean by *cpp* so have no idea if it is a solution or not.  And if you read my comment to the first Q I reference, you might understand that I am not persuaded of the *need* for variable rank arrays.  And I'm commenting precisely because I am not planning to answer.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark. I posted an answer using cpp. I know it is ugly, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical example where object-oriented programming helps.
You have two programs that respond to the same API, but internal computations will be different (2D or 3D).
You want to have 2d and 3d grids both extend a generic "grid type"

```
module grids
   implicit none

   type, abstract, public :: grid
      contains
      procedure (grid_init), deferred :: init
   end type grid

   type, public, extends(grid) :: grid2D
      real, allocatable :: myArray(:,:)
      contains
         procedure :: init=>init_2d
   end type grid2D
   
   type, public, extends(grid) :: grid3D
      real, allocatable :: myArray(:,:,:)
      contains
         procedure :: init=>init_3d
   end type grid3D

   ! Define procedure APIs 
   abstract interface
      subroutine grid_init(this,size)
         import grid
         class(grid), intent(inout) :: this
         integer, intent(in) :: size
      end subroutine grid_init
   end interface

   contains

   ! Define ACTUAL procedures for the 2d and 3d grids
   subroutine init_3d(this, size)
      class(grid3D), intent(inout) :: this
      integer, intent(in) :: size
      allocate(this%myArray(size, size,size))
   end subroutine init_3d
   subroutine init_2d(this, size)
      class(grid2D), intent(inout) :: this
      integer, intent(in) :: size
      allocate(this%myArray(size,size))
   end subroutine init_2d
end module grids
```

The actual implementation is up to you, but the key points are:

- Expose all common "operations" (on a grid, for example) through the polymorphic API; define them in the `abstract` class, so the compiler will check that all you've done in the child classes is right;
- Hide all dimension-dependent code and data inside the derived types;
- Ideally, you would try to define all routines of your public interface in a dimension-independent way. This is often not possible, in which case, you'll revert to use type-checking in those places where a shared call is not possible.

For example, you may need 2 or 3 input parameters to something: you can do

```
class(grid), allocatable :: myGrid

select type (myGrid)
   type is (grid2D); [...]
   type is (grid3D); [...]
   class default; [...]
end select
```

A simple test program will look like

```
program test_grids
   use grids
   implicit none

   type(grid2D) :: fixed_2d
   type(grid3D) :: fixed_3d
   class(grid), allocatable :: polymorphic

   ! Initialize non-polymorphic grids (fixed type)
   call fixed_2d%init(5)
   call fixed_3d%init(10)

   ! Initialize polymorphic grid as 2D
   allocate(grid2D :: polymorphic)
   call polymorphic%init(10)

   ! Initialize polymorphic grid as 3D
   deallocate(polymorphic)
   allocate(grid3D :: polymorphic)
   call polymorphic%init(10)

end program test_grids
```

Hope this helps,
Federico

Comment: @federicp. Thanks for your answer. I am discovering polymorphism in fortran (abstract interface, abstract type ...). I still have a problem with your code. `call grid_init(myGrid,5` returns an error (myGrid is `class(grid2D), allocatable :: myGrid`)? Could you give me an complete example ?

Comment: If you have 
`class(grid2D), allocatable :: myGrid`
then your variable can only be `grid2D` or any inherited types, so you want to define it with the root class, i.e., 
`class(grid), allocatable :: myGrid`.

Plus, when you have a polymorphic object, you always have to call routines through the type interface, e.g.: `call grid%init(...)` and not the non-polymorphic versions like `call init_2d(....)`.  Only with the first method there is polymorphism

Comment: Not sure to well understand. Now, it is compiling but there is a segmentation fault. I suppose, if I want to work with 2D (or3D) arrays, I declare then as grid2D (or grid3D) in the main ?

Comment: The main program I used is very simple : `class(grid2D), allocatable :: myGrid`, `call myGrid%init(5)`

Comment: I've added a simple example program

Comment: Thanks a lot. I discovered my problem just before you sent this example. I declared my variable with `class` and not `type`. I got the explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29652905/7462275

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is ugly but it works and it is convenient to use

```
#define nDim 3

#if nDim==2
#  define xdimCpp :,:
#  define xboundsCpp(X) 1:X,1:X
#elif nDim = 3
#  define xdimCpp :,:,:
#  define xboundsCpp(X) 1:X,1:X,1:X
#endif
  
program main

    integer :: size
    real, dimension(xdimCpp,:), allocatable :: myArray

    size=4 ! Normally read from a file
    allocate(myArray(xboundsCpp(size),1:nDim))
    call initArray(myArray)
    print *,myArray
    
contains
    
    subroutine initArray(myArray)
    
        real, dimension(xboundsCpp(size),1:nDim) :: myArray
    
        myArray(xboundsCpp(size),1:nDim) = 5.d0
     
        return  
    end subroutine initArray
    
end program main
```